# How to make unique datasets for each value of a dataset

Tags: r

I've been tasked with making multiple graphs using values from a specific data set (21 values so 21 graphs). I was sent a script to assist me however I'm a little unfamiliar with the 'gridExtra' packages and the entirety of the p -> part.

Could anyone help explain this code to me, or suggest how I can separate individual data into individual graphs?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
data=read.csv("tubgal4crosses.csv")
str(data)
datasum=aggregate(Count~Gene+Sex+Markers,FUN=sum,data=data)

genes=unique(data$Gene)

p<-list()
i=1
while(i<(length(genes)+1)){
  p[[i]]<-ggplot(data=subset(datasum,Gene==genes[i]), aes(x=Markers, y=Count, fill=Sex)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
    theme_minimal()


  p[[i]] + scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))
  p[[i]] + ggtitle(genes[i])

  i=i+1
}
pdf("scop.pdf")
do.call(grid.arrange,p)
dev.off()
```

Comment: In your code ```p``` is  a list that contains i graphs (one per genes). Calling each p[[i]] (p[[1]], p[[2]], ...) and saving each of them into a pdf would certainly do the trick.

Comment: `p` is a list of plots constructed via the [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html#learning-ggplot2) system, while [gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) allows for arrangement of those plots in the same graph. I'm voting to close this question, because it is not specific enough to generate effective answers. I suggest creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specifying the desired output for that MCVE.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'll go over the code a little bit now I have a slight better understanding and hopefully post a more revised, direct question if I still can't figure it out!